# Is there an AliExpress API to request product reviews?

Tags: import, aliexpress

I'm trying to retrieve reviews from AliExpress and was hoping there would be an API I could do this with but I haven't had any luck finding one.

I've looked through the documentation on their website (https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=108088&docType=1) and the only mention to reviews I could find was on the `aliexpress.postproduct.redefining.findaeproductbyidfordropshipper` request (https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=35321&docType=2) with properties `evaluation_count` and `avg_evaluation_rating`.

Perhaps there's another API that I should be looking at? I'd like to avoid having to scrape the data if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I have written a **scraper** and made it available as an npm package. This would give you complete information about the product as `json` response. You would receive feedbacks, product images, description, product info including stock details etc.,

https://github.com/sudheer-ranga/aliexpress-product-scraper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aliexpress-product-scraper

Install the npm package
`npm i aliexpress-product-scraper`

Get product details:

```
const scrape = require('aliexpress-product-scraper');
const product = scrape('32958933105');

product.then(res => {
  console.log('Product Details JSON: ', res);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! There seem to be no options to change the site locale or the number of feedback pages?

Comment: Could be also nice to be able to specify from which reviews page to continue (to be able to chunk it in multiple calls)

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this service](https://www.reviewshake.com/review-scraper-api/scrape-aliexpress-reviews). Haven't used it myself though. It's a paid service and a bit pricey in my opinion.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please add some explanation and quotes.